# Images with a style applied loses quality immediately even before saving

Tags: image-quality, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a number of very good quality photos inserted into PowerPoint 2016. There are over 30 of them and to keep it easy for the client to update them later I simply applied a style (simple white boarder with a drop shadow) to each.

As I applied these I noticed the quality of the photo drops noticeably as soon as the style is applied.

Is there any way around this? I have set the save to keep the quality of the original images (client wants to print so it was designed to A3 and will be compressed a bit more when finalized.)

Comment: Why would you be using Powerpoint for a project designed to be printed? PowerPoint is *specifically* designed for screen presentations.

Comment: Being a designer of over 16 years I do understand the sentiment behind the comment and as much as I want to agree with you, but there are two things you are overlooking. Firstly is flexibility to work around client needs, they are not designers by a long shot so I go to a space they know. In this case this is painfully, PowerPoint. Secondly, PowerPoint offers A4 as a slide size, this is a round about way that the coders hinted that you may want to print these slides. Believe me, if I could get them into Corel Draw, Affinity Designer or Photoshop I would be a more happy camper.

Comment: I was just thinking PDF.... you can print and make presentations. But if the client wants to edit themselves, I get it. I have one client that insists on PowerPoint, but they aren't printing the presentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not inserted a photo on Power Point since ages, because it always made a marmalade out of them.

There is a chance they corrected this but Power Point is not the best vehicle to deliver photos. I would send them the originals or send a PDF.

So this answer could be not an exact one.

I gess the style is applied directly to the photo, so it is reinterpreted/resampled to be viewed on screen.

Options:

**1.** If all the images are the same size you could **make a background** on the slides simulating the shadow, and insert the image above it. This way the "style" is not applied to the original photos.

**2.** If you are making some kind of catalog, try a specific software.

Specialized Desktop Publishing Systems do one thing... or more exactly do not do one thing, they do not insert an image into the file, they link them, so the good quality images stay outside the document, and that is the best way to update them. You can simply override the original image.

There are some free options (if that is what is stoping you to use them)

**a)** Scribus https://www.scribus.net/

**b)** Page Plus Starter http://www.serif.com/desktop-publishing-software/ (Reed the licence please)

**c)** You can even try publisher... Ouch I bited myself...

**d)** You can even prepare a simple webpage, where you simply update the images on a folder.

The client must choose between two things. Just be unwilling to learn and having a poor quality print, or learn something new and have a better product.

But try the option 1. Using a background on power point so the images stay untouched.

Comment: So the answer is, not PowerPoint. I'm feeling this is a "no-win" situation. Perhaps I need to get them to use some thing else, the question of what (free, really free, its a corporate environment with managed computer systems.) package can some one with little or no design knowledge can use to do the same thing? I know about PhotoScape being a decent option.

Comment: Let me edit my answer with some recomendations. But try to explain more why the client needs to update photos, Is that a catalog or something?